Running electrical behind cabinets with old plaster walls
Working on a kitchen renovation, planning on installing cabinets using blocking because the plumbing/electrical are affixed to old plaster/concrete walls.
I want to make sure I'm up to code because one circuit was literally dangling in the back of the old cabinets and the garbage disposal wiring is buried in the plaster wall.
Code says "protected from damage" -- how would you guys approach the electrical along this wall? Regular old romex that has cable straps every 3 feet? Armored cable? Wiremold raceway with romex? Conduit with THHN? There is going to be a sink along this wall, FYSA.
Additionally, I would like the wiring concealed when it goes vertical to the outlets above the countertops. I think conduit would work as a channel in the wall but I want to make sure this is allowed.

the blue line in this image is the garbage disposal circuit running up from the crawl space that is buried in the wall.

Usually inside a home, protection means not having cable visible.  Inside of walls(drywall, not sure about plaster) and not being able to use to hang wet clothes/chewed on by kids/pets.

Blocking the cabinets out would work to hide the plumbing and wiring, but create a new set of problems with the standard counter depth no longer fitting.  This is requiring custom counters=$$.  Upper  cabinets would also be at an uncomfortable distance from the counter edge.  Consider building a wall/s floor to ceiling to contain the plumbing and wiring.

Looks like you're gonna need to notch out the back of the cabinets anyway for the plumbing?

With blocking, we should be okay without having to notch the cabinets too bad, just standard penetrations for waste and supply. But that would create a small 2-3inch void space behind the cabinets which is where I'm running the wiring. Want to make sure I'm doing best practices with the wiring.

I had anticipated increased dimensions on the countertops but not the inflated price due to custom sizing! So thanks for that consideration. This wall will be easy to do a 16oc stud wall but the wall opposite and out of frame will be impossible (more wiring, more plumbing) with pipes literally flush with the floor/bottom of the concrete wall so no space for a bottom plate.

Crip659 and others, could I get away with a small 2 foot run of conduit that is channeled in the wall and then plastered over so the romex isn't visible to the outlets?
